# Dockerfile in a Amazon EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Dockerfile into Amazon EB using the console

After execute `eb init` and `eb create` I can't make it run. Even an easier Dockerfile with an `nginx` hello world like [this](https://github.com/mattes/hello-world-nginx)

For some reason the `ADD` command in the `Dockerfile` is not working

Any clue about how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of differences between the `ADD` and `COPY` directives (see https://labs.ctl.io/dockerfile-add-vs-copy/), and in your use case, `COPY` is preferable.

Try:

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.